# 君を思う気持ち meaning and nuance

Tags: sentence

I am listening to a song and came across 君を思う気持ち. I thought it just means "the feeling of thinking about you", but apparently not. Looking at the lyrics translation, it means "you are always on my mind", but I can't even begin to fathom how it means that. Is the translation right? If not, what does it actually mean? Looking at jisho 思う really doesn't sway too much from meaning "think"

Comment: Typo: 持ち in title and 持 in the first line. → 気持ち ?

Comment: @kimiTanaka 書き直した

Comment: ありがとうございます。個人的にはどちらの翻訳が正しいと言うよりかは好き好きだと思います。Is it really that different "the feeling of thinking about you" and "you are always on my mind". I am non-native speaker of English language though.

Comment: @Newbie How about "caring about you"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see where you are coming from. 君を思う気持ち as a noun phrase would literally translate to "the feeling of thinking about you", but that just fails to convey what it *means*.

君を思う isn't just "I'm thinking about you." It's a confession of love, in a little more indirect, elegant, graceful way that is so wonderfully Japanese. So how would you translate that? "I love you" would be just too blunt and lacks grace. I think "you are always on my mind" is a much better one, assuming it's put in a proper context.

Comment: Thanks. Wow, never expected it to be a love confession! From the sound of it, I'm guessing it's somewhere between 好き and 愛している？ More than 好き but less than 愛している

Comment: @Newbie IMO trying to put them on a single linear scale misses the point, but with that said I can generally affirm what you are saying. A heterosexial male can use 好き to refer to another male, say his best friend, but I can't picture a circumstance where 君を思う気持ち would be appropriate in that same situation.